# Фортепьяны / фортепьяно

Tags: орфография

Лермонтов:

> Княгиня  усадила  дочь  за  фортепьяны;

Прим.: в некот. изданиях в данной фразе исп-ся «фортепьяно».

[Справка](https://www.royali.info/royal):

> Архаичные крыловидные инструменты ранее в России называли фортепиано (фортепианы) или флигель (искаж. нем. flügel — крыло).

Вопросы:

1. Каково происхождение версии с «ы»?
2. Версия с «ы» считалась нормативной? (Судя по Лермонтову, да.)
3. Когда (хотя бы прибл.) произошло вытеснение «ы» «о»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Из "Этимологического словаря русского языка"<sup>1</sup> М. Фасмера:

> **фортепья́но** также *фортепьян* м. (напр., у Чехова), часто во мн. ч.: *на фортепьянах* (И. Толстой). Через стар. нов.-в.-н. Fortepiano (часто, начиная с 1775 г.; см. Шульц-Баслер 2, 519 и сл.) или непосредственно из ит. fоrtерiаnо; русск. форма м. р., возм., через польск. fortepian; см. Горяев, ЭС 393.

*Фортепьяны* это винительный падеж множественного числа слова *фортепьян*. В русском языке одну штуку музыкального инструмента часто называли множественным *фортепьяны* или *пианины*.

2. Что есть норма для дореформенного языка? Общего свода правил не существовало, отчего и такая большая вариативность в дореволюционных источниках.

3. В первом издании Даля<sup>2</sup> (1863, но часть П — 1865) слово уже фиксируется как несклоняемое *пiано*, *пiанофорте*, *фортепiано* и *пiанино*. Значит, к тому моменту слово уже должно было считаться несклоняемым какое-то время.

Причем у самого Даля, в его "Вакх Сидоров Чайкин, или Рассказ его о собственном своем житье-бытье, за первую половину жизни своей" (1843) используется архаическая форма *фортепьяны*, например в названии главы IX:

> От чемодана, в котором добра немного, до фортепъян с турецким барабаном

Точнее назвать дату "вытеснения" мне кажется невозможным: то ли в шутку, то ли для придания оттенка старины, вариант множественного числа используется в литературе до сих пор, а уж в устной речи тем более.

Из источников середины XIX века можно увидеть архаичный вариант, например, у Бакунина (письмо 1 мая 1845):

> В соседней комнате Рейхель играет на фортепьянах, чистый утренний воздух освежил мою комнату и наполнил ее весенним благоуханием цветов, стоящих у меня на окне.

Отмечу, что к этому моменту Бакунин уже 5 лет как покинул Россию.

Из письма Толстого (17 ноября 1856):

> У меня хорошенькая, тихая квартерка, стоят фортепьяно, и наши перья с ИИ скрыпят от утра до вечера.

В некоторых версиях указывается *фортепьяны*, но это всё перепечатки, а электронную версию оригинала так просто не найти.

Рекомендую также посмотреть статью Н.Ф. Ивановой  "Фортепьяны, фортепьян или рояля?"<sup>3</sup>, об употреблении этого термина в творчестве Чехова (конец XIXв.). Ею высказывается гипотеза о том, что форма множественного *фортепианы* происходит по аналогии с *клавикорды*, вызванное схожестью инструментов.

---

1. Фасмер М. Этимологический словарь русского языка: В 4 т.: Пер. с нем. = Russisches etymologisches Wörterbuch / Перевод и дополнения О. Н. Трубачёва. — 4-е изд., стереотип. — М.: Астрель — АСТ, 2004.
2. Толковый словарь живаго великорускаго языка В. И. Даля. — М.: Издание Общ-ва любителей российской словесности, 1863—1866.
3. Иванова Н. Ф. Фортепьяны, фортепьян или рояля? Вестник Новгородского государственного университета им. Ярослава Мудрого. – 2015. – №. 7 (90).