# "Кресла" или "кресло"?

Tags: орфография, устаревшие-слова

Лермонтов:

> Он сел в кресла...

> ...она сидела в тени у окна, погружаясь в широкие кресла…

> ...она опустилась в кресла

> Она выпрямилась в креслах...

С [фортепьянами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/463612/195473) ясно. Что с креслами?

Comment: Посмотрите значения 2 и 3 [здесь](https://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=25906), для примера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В толковом словаре Ушакова (**1935—1940**) имеется такая информация:
[кресло](http://endic.ru/dal/Kreslo-13933.html)
3. *только мн.* То же, что кресло (устар.). *Развалился в креслах.*

В толковом словаре Даля (**1863—1866**) слово "кресло" стоит на первом месте (кресло, ср. или кресла мн.). Это означает, что уже тогда эта форма превалировала.

Достаточно посмотреть статистику Нацкорпуса.
[Уселся в кресла](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0)
Последний текст — 1877 год (предложения Тынянова — это стилистика "под Пушкина").
[Уселась в кресла](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) — 1863 год (Евсеев — о XVIII веке).

Так что в повседневной жизни устарели *кресла* уже очень давно.

Comment: "Кресла" устарели, конечно, но не настолько. [Здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85) можно встретить и Булгакова, и Тынянова, и даже Ольгу Форш. Если в запросе задать просто "в креслах", то там можно встретить довольно много примеров в литературе этого века, но, понятно, что там намного чаще встретится обычное употребление.

Comment: Поддержал ответ, но немного жаль, что Вы не упомянули значение 2 в словаре Ушакова. Во времена Ушакова это значение ещё не было устаревшим, но у Кузнецова теперь уже устаревшее (а значение 3 в нём и вовсе не упомянуто).

Comment: Спасибо. Можно, конечно, и добавить. Просто я подумала, что в примерах из Лермонтова речь  никак не идет о театре. А ссылочка-то ведь имеется — всегда ж можно посмотреть-почитать.

Comment: Не понимаю, как можно было одно кресло называть креслами. Вот это самое интересное. Может, они были соединены (как в театре), ну или связано с такими креслами.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Для платья с кринолином нужно широкое кресло, а то и два (если поставить рядом, то ведь это все-таки кресла, не диван). Или что-то вроде дюшесса. (https://mebel-news.pro/articles/the-history-of-furniture/history-of-ordinary-things-classical-armchair/)

Comment: Интересная картинка (не знал о таком). Гугл-поиск показывает лишь одинарные старинные кресла.